# remove node from nodelist jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assumption: `(".class")` returns a `nodeList`...

I have a grid `div` with five child `div`s that all have `button`s. When a `button` is clicked that `div` should expand and the others will have some other styles applied to them . The div to expand is referenced by `boxToExpand` while `boxesToFallInLine` should reference the other four `div` items. However, I cannot achieve this. I store all five elements in `boxesToFallInLine` and then attempt to use `boxesToFallInLine.remove(boxToExpand)` but this does not seem to be working. Here is my code:

```js
 let btn = $('button');
    btn.on("click", function(){
      let btnId = $(this).attr('id');
      let boxId = boxIdFormat(btnId);
      let boxToExpand = $("#" + boxId); //Element to expand
      //code to expand omitted

      let boxesToFallInLine = $(".box"); //all box elements
      boxesToFallInLine.remove(boxToExpand); //Remove the one that was expanded (This doesn't appear to remove the node)
      boxes.ToFallInline.css("background", "blue"); //Just a test. All five elements are now blue
    });

    //Converts "box1-btn" to "box1"
    function boxIdFormat(btnId){
      return btnId.split('-')[0];
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
        <div class="box" id = "box1">
            <button id="box1-btn">Expand</button>
          </div>
          <div class="box"  id = "box2">
            <button id="box2-btn">Expand</button>
          </div>
          <div class="box"  id = "box3">
            <button id="box3-btn">Expand</button>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you mention a `NodeList` when you're using jQuery? There's no `NodeList` involved.

Comment: If it isn't a typo in your pasted code - you are missing a " after the word blue.

Comment: [`.remove( [selector] )`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/): _"Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM."_, `selector`: _"Type: **string**; A selector expression that filters the set of matched elements to be removed."_ - With `boxesToFallInLine.remove(boxToExpand)` you're telling jQuery to remove all elements from `boxesToFallInLine` that match the selector `[object Object]`.

Comment: @Andreas does it return an HTMLCollection?

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to grab the ID and from the `this` element and query the DOM of the element with that ID as they're the same. That is, `$( this )` is the same as `$( '#' + boxID )`. If you need the ID for your other function use `boxToExpand.attr( 'id' )`.

Comment: @user3131132 jQuery return a jQuery object/collection. A [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) is a native JS API that stores elements. Though they have some similarities, they are not the same.

Comment: u can simply remove using selector
 boxToExpand.remove()

Comment: @hungerstar thanks for both comments. I thought `$('.class');` did the exact same thing as `document.getElementsByClassName('class');` just in a less verbose way, was not aware it returned something different.

Comment: The reason it returns something different is that almost everything in jQuery is chainable, so everything returns "an object with the same basic jQuery API ". As such, if you need to remove all matched items, you use `$("some query selector").remove()`. You don't manually iterate over all the elements in whatever `$("some query selector")` returns. As for your question: you're calling `boxIdFormat`, which splits on `-`, and your HTML doesn't have any `id` attributes with hyphens in them, so fix that. Instead of messing with the id element, just get the surrounding div using `$(this).parent()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it returns something different is that almost everything in jQuery is chainable, so everything returns "an object with the same basic jQuery API ". As such, if you need to update items, you use `$("some query selector").someFunction()` like `remove` or `css` etc. This is in stark contrast to the DOM API `HTMLCollection` and `NodeList`, which are simply objects without any way to chain DOM or CSSOM operations onto them.

As for your question: you're calling `boxIdFormat(btnId)`, which is a function that splits a string on `-`, and your HTML doesn't have any id attributes with hyphens in them. So that's very clearly not going to work.

Instead of guessing the parent by messing with strings and then querying with recomposed strings, just *get the parent directly*: if you have a reference to the button, the button knows what its parent is. And with that knowledge, you can form a single jQuery chain that gets all boxes, removes the one with the clicked button in it (using [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)), and then modifies the css for the remaining ones:

```
$(`button`).click(function() {
  let cbox = $(this).parent();

  // do something with `box` here, like...
  cbox.css(`background`,`inherit`);

  // then update everything else:
  $(".box").not(cbox).css(`background`, `blue`); 
})
```

Done, no need for guess work.

(Also  to anyone tempted to turn that into an arrow function, like `btn.click(evt => {...})`: resist that urge. jQuery needs to be able to rebind the execution context for event handlers (i.e. what `this` points to inside the function) which arrow functions don't allow and will in fact ignore without any error or warning)